# Direct VoIP call from one iOS device to another

Tags: iphone, ios, sip, voip, pjsip

I'am going to develop peer-to-peer VoIP iOS application. And want do it without any SIP proxy,  SIP providers and other servers. Just VoIP calls frpm iOSdevice-to-iOSdevice. Both iOS device could be somewhere in Internet. Is it real in VoIP (with PJSIP for example and general with SIP)?

Could you please point me to main keys that I need for development.

I have already read [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516133/how-can-i-make-call-between-direct-ip-to-ip-without-sip-server) [topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705746/peer-2-peer-call-using-pjsip-and-pjsua/12515187#12515187). Is it real solve problems with addressing in my configuration. PJSIP could help with correcting addressing?

Comment: Hello @user1682856 have u found any perfect solution for this. actually i am looking for same now a days so need your help in this.

Comment: me too looking to achieve the same.

Answer (score 2):

Look at Apples Multipeer Connectivity framework. I have built an app that does exactly what you want. If you look to my profile and the questions I have asked you will get some good guidance. Though I recommend you do it with a backend since MultiPeer wasn't the best solution, atleast when it comes to supporting multiple peers and to be able to call another device that has the app in the background.

Comment: Oh, didn't see the question was asked four years ago. Hope it helps someone though.

Answer (score 1):

See Frank Shearar's Answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705746/peer-2-peer-call-using-pjsip-and-pjsua?lq=1)

In short, it looks like this would be a very difficult task.

Another option would be to use the Twilio SDK for iPhone (Obj-C). This would work well for what you're trying to do and would be a whole lot easier. [Link](http://www.twilio.com/client)